# Changing IE version being used with Lotus Sametime 8.5.2

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, swt, lotus, sametime

We are using IE (Browser Control) inside Sametime 8.5.2 The problem on few of the systems is that Sametime is using IE version 8 instead of system installed version 10 and it spoils the whole Web page.
How to make Lotus Sametime use the system installed browser(IE)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the sametime client embedded in the Lotus/IBM Notes client, you can change the browser being used by following the below.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/notestipsblog.nsf/dx/how-to-change-the-default-browser-for-notes